# Using scipy.minimize to find the maximum likelihood estimates for multivariate gaussian

Tags: optimization, scipy, gaussian, parameter-estimation, multivariate-distribution

Let's say I have a 100x2 normally distributed array of data.

```py
   In [2]: import numpy as np
   ...:
   ...: # instantiate a random number generator
   ...: rng = np.random.default_rng(100)
   ...:
   ...: # define mu and sigma for the dummy sample
   ...: mu = np.array([0.5, 0.25])
   ...: cov = np.array([[1, 0.5],
   ...:                 [0.5, 1]])
   ...:
   ...: # generate multivariate normal random sample
   ...: x = rng.multivariate_normal(mu, cov, size=100)
   ...:
   ...: print(x.shape)
(100, 2)
```

I want to find the maximum likelihood estimates of parameters $\vec{\mu}$ and $\Sigma$ using the scipy minimize function. Finding the maxima of the log-likelihood is equivalent to finding the minima of the $-\log(\mathcal{L})$.

$$-\log(\mathcal{L}) = -l(\vec{\mu}, \Sigma) = \frac{1}{2}[nk\ln(2\pi) + n\ln(\det(\Sigma^{-1})) + \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(\vec{x} - \vec{\mu})^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})]$$

```py
def log_likelihood(params, x):
    mu, covmat = params
    print(mu, covmat)
    x = x[:, np.newaxis] # add a new first dimension to x
    k = mu.shape[0]  # number of dimensions
    n = x.shape[1]  # number of samples
    inv_covmat = np.linalg.inv(covmat)  # inverse of the covariance matrix
    diff = x - mu  # deviation of x from the mean
    maha_dist = np.einsum('ijk, kl, ijl->ij', diff, inv_covmat, diff) # mahalabonis distance

    term1 = n*k*np.log(2*np.pi)
    term2 = n*np.log(np.linalg.det(inv_cov))
    term3 = np.sum(maha_dist, axis=0)
    return 0.5 * (term1 + term2 + term3)
```

My initial idea of how to minimise this likelihood function with respect to the parameters using `scipy.optimize` is shown below.

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# initial guesses
mu_guess = [0, 0]
covmat_guess = [[1, 0],
                [0, 1]]

lik_model = minimize(log_likelihood, x0=(mu_guess, covmat_guess), args=x)

lik_model.x
```

But I am getting the following error. I presume it has something to do with the shapes of my initial guesses, but I don't know how else I can represent them.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [20], in <cell line: 6>()
      2 mu_guess = [0, 0]
      3 covmat_guess = [[1, 0],
      4                 [0, 1]]
----> 6 lik_model = minimize(log_likelihood, x0=(mu_guess, covmat_guess), args=x)
      8 lik_model.x

File ~/miniforge3/envs/minimise/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py:687, in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    685     res = _minimize_cg(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
    686 elif meth == 'bfgs':
--> 687     res = _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
    688 elif meth == 'newton-cg':
    689     res = _minimize_newtoncg(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp, callback,
    690                              **options)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/minimise/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:1296, in _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, gtol, norm, eps, maxiter, disp, return_all, finite_diff_rel_step, **unknown_options)
   1293 if maxiter is None:
   1294     maxiter = len(x0) * 200
-> 1296 sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,
   1297                               finite_diff_rel_step=finite_diff_rel_step)
   1299 f = sf.fun
   1300 myfprime = sf.grad

File ~/miniforge3/envs/minimise/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:263, in _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac, args, bounds, epsilon, finite_diff_rel_step, hess)
    259     bounds = (-np.inf, np.inf)
    261 # ScalarFunction caches. Reuse of fun(x) during grad
    262 # calculation reduces overall function evaluations.
--> 263 sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,
    264                     finite_diff_rel_step, bounds, epsilon=epsilon)
    266 return sf

File ~/miniforge3/envs/minimise/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py:107, in ScalarFunction.__init__(self, fun, x0, args, grad, hess, finite_diff_rel_step, finite_diff_bounds, epsilon)
    101     raise ValueError("Whenever the gradient is estimated via "
    102                      "finite-differences, we require the Hessian "
    103                      "to be estimated using one of the "
    104                      "quasi-Newton strategies.")
    106 # the astype call ensures that self.x is a copy of x0
--> 107 self.x = np.atleast_1d(x0).astype(float)
    108 self.n = self.x.size
    109 self.nfev = 0

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem actually was the problem.

I have since learned that the covariance matrix was to be assumed as a constant and it is in fact only the mean which is to be determined.

Removing this requirement also removes the exception detailed above.